# Zipping two list of length 2

Tags: python, list

What I'm trying to do is suppose you're given two list, each with 2 elements in them. And if you take the zip of the two list and it produces a result in the form of [x, y] or [y, x] than it should return True otherwise return False. And suppose commutativity holds. (x,y= y,x)

ex. say x = [1, 2] and y = [2, 1]

Zipping the list will give -> [[1,2], [2,1]] and since that is the same as [x,y] it should return True.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
print([list(i) for i in zip(x, y)] == [x, y] or [list(i) for i in zip(x, y)] == [y, x])
```

What my code does:

```
x = [1, 2]
y = [2, 1]

[list(i) for i in zip(x, y)] -> [[1, 2], [2,1]]
[[1, 2], [2,1]] = [x, y] so return True.
```

Since the left and right sides are equal then it should return True.

But the problem with what I have now is that suppose x and y are:

```
x = [[1, 2], 2]
y = [1, [1, 2]]

[list(i) for i in zip(x, y)] -> [[[1, 2], 1], [2, [1,2]]]
```

this should return True since the result, [[[1, 2], 1], [2, [1,2]]] is [y,x] and

```
[[1, 2], 1] = [1, [1, 2]] = y (commutative)
[2, [1,2]] = [[1, 2], 2] = x (commutative)
```

However mine returns False and I can't figure out where I went wrong. I was wondering if anyone can point out where I went wrong and what I can do to resolve it.

Comment: A list is ordered, so you'd need to permute all combinations and test equality.

Comment: I've read the question three times, and I am struggling to understand the problem statement.

Comment: I don’t get your problem, but I think you should use sets instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this instead (which I changed slightly based on @poke's recommendation):

```
>>> def commutate(x, y):
    return x == y[::-1]

>>> x, y = [1, 2], [2, 1]
>>> commutate(x, y)
True
>>> commutate([[1, 2], 1], [1, [1, 2]])
True
```

Comment: Your “commutate” (which isn’t a word), is equal to `x == y[::-1]`.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I think I was overthinking the problem using zip and so on. Didn't think it would be this easy(basically 2 lines).

Comment: Incidentally, commutate *is* a word (meaning "to change", unless used in reference to electricity), although this is merely an aside.

Answer (score 0):

`List` are ordered, so you need to check if each element of first list is `in` the second one, something like:

```
a = [[1, 2], 1] 
b = [1, [1, 2]]

def equal(list1, list2):
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            return False
    return True

print equal(a,b)
```